# rails dyamically add fields to nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I have followed Ryans railscast #196 (revised) in order to dynamically add and remove fields to a nested form.  It seems to be working just fine but I am having two issues.

1. I have 2 fields in the nested form (child area) that use the JQuery datepicker and as such have a class on them in the partial that displays the initial records.  Initially the form is created with just 1 child.  On this 1st child row the datepicker works just fine.  However, when a new row is added the 2 fields with the datepicker no longer work.  I believe the issue is due to the fact that when the new record gets created it does not assign the class to them, therefore the JS will not work :( No idea how to go about attempting to fix this, if it's even possible.  If this is not possible then do I need to have a button to add a new record that will basically do this and refresh the form?  I am hoping there's a way to do this dynamically since it just looks smoother.
2. When I go to edit the above record the same 2 fields are not showing the actual dates.  The dates are fine and I can see that they are saved in the DB.  I have another form that has a date field with the datepicker but that field is at the header and it is showing a value when editing the field.  Obviously, the code I have to set the value of the date field is just not working.  Again, would appreciate some help.  The code is below for the partial view of these two fields.

   ```
   <% fromdate_display = :fromdate %>
   <%= f.text_field fromdate_display,  placeholder: "mm/dd/yyyy", required: true, id: "price_fromdate", value: :fromdate.try(:strftime, "%m/%d/%Y") %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :fromdate, id: "price_fromdatealt" %>


   <% todate_display = :todate %>
   <%= f.text_field todate_display,  placeholder: "mm/dd/yyyy", required: true, id: "price_todate", value: :todate.try(:strftime, "%m/%d/%Y") %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :todate, id: "price_todatealt" %>
   ```

I have tried changing the value: to be something as follows, but that throws an error:

```
value: @plan.plan_prices.fromdate.try(:strftime, "%m/%d/%Y")
```

Error message thrown:

```
undefined method `fromdate' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_PlanPrice:0x36eb428>
```

Comment: I think I have fixed the second issue, at least partially.  I can now see the dates when editing a record.  I needed to put a line in the edit part of my controller to find the plan_price record by ID.  I'm having other issues but I am still looking into those and will post a separate question on that if I cannot resolve.

Answer (score 0):

I think the datepicker inputs dont work because are added dynamically after the datepicker plugin is loaded. Try to call the js plugin after you add a new input, maybe in the click event of link that add the inputs. Or try use this gem https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon. By the way, what plugin you use for datepickers?

Comment: I don't believe I am using a plug in, I am using JQuery which I think is part of RoR 4.x.  I'm not sure I understand your answer though.  The datepicker works just fine on the initial row, it is just on the dynamically added rows it does not work.

Comment: Armando, how would I call the JS plugin again after the new record has been added?